# 32-bit Unicode strings in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Unicode strings are mentioned with an escape sequence `\u`. However this works only for 16-bit unicode strings.

That is:

```
CREATE (a:Person {name : "\u1020"})
```

will work as usual, but the problem is with 32 bit unicode strings.

For e.g:

```
CREATE (a:Person {name : "\U10201020"})
```

will give an error as

```
Invalid input 'U': expected '\', ''', '"', 'b', 'f', 'n', 'r', 't' or Unicode (line 1, column 28)
```

Or using :- `\u` itself

```
CREATE (a:Person {name : "\u10201020"})
```

will be very wrong.

The question is how do I represent 32-bit unicode strings in Neo4j?

Comment: Why do you want to use 32-bit unicode literals?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At this time (as of **2.2.0-M02** and all previous releases), Cypher only supports the `\u` literal with *16 bit unicode*.

The **Neo4j 2.2.0 GA** release will contain support for *UTF-32* literals, using the upper case `\Uxxxxxxxx` form.

Comment: Do you work for neo4j, if yes then when will you release the version with support for 32 bit?

Comment: Is there a reason you're looking for UTF-32 support? Couldn't you recode it as a UTF-16 surrogate-pair? i.e. your example codepoint U+10201020 could possibly be written as "\uDBC8\uDC1020".

Comment: The problem is that my database has 1GB of data and 60% is in UTF-32

Comment: For a large dataset, writing it as literals inside Cypher would not be very performant. Can I suggest you use parameters and pass the strings, already converted, along with the query?

Comment: I rather like your other suggestion. Do you have any algorithm to convert 32-bit UTF to 16 bit?

Comment: There's various tools for that out there. And here's a manual conversion table: http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/surrogatetable.html

Comment: Added my answer to help others. Still accepting your answer as it was the basis of mine. (Ult mot - I'll get +2 rep :P ). Thanks again.

Comment: Just so you know, I've made sure Neo4j 2.2.0 GA release will contain support for UTF-32 using \Uxxxxxxxx (https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/pull/3779).

Comment: Thanks for that. (If possible, add a link to this question so that the Neo4j guys understand how freakin tough it is at present) ... :p

Comment: No need. I am part of the Neo4j guys :)

Answer (score 2):

As Chris Leishman mentioned in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27695012/32-bit-uncode-strings-in-neo4j#comment43948285_27762640), it is possible if we split it into surrogate pairs.

The surrogate pairs can be calculated by using a very simple formula. The code to do so in Python is

```
H = ((S - 0x10000) // 0x400) + 0xD800;
L = ((S - 0x10000) % 0x400) + 0xDC00;
```

For example if `S` is `\U00101020` then `H` will become `\udbc4` and `L` will become `\udc20`. In this way we can convert

```
CREATE (a:Person {name : "\U100101020"})
```

to

```
CREATE (a:Person {name : "\udbc4\udc20"})
```

which will work on Neo4j.